# How can I get a listing of all storage ports available?

Tags: laptop, hardware, storage, sata, nvme

I have a laptop (Asus X421IA) and im trying to figure out what kind of storage expansion possibilities I have. Asus's lineup being a mess, I couldn't find the manual info for my exact model on their website. I was wondering if I could see a listing of sata + nvme ports available via software instead. All i could find is a listing of ports in use, which is not what I want.

I also tried using `hwinfo --short` which gave me the following :

```
storage:
                       Samsung Electronics Non-Volatile memory controller
                       AMD FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
                       AMD FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
```

Not too sure what info I can get out of this tho, does it mean I have two sata ports available ? If not what can I use to figure out if i can add a drive, be it a 2.5" or M.2 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read `man lshw` and do `sudo lshw`, or check the manufacturer's description. "Laptops" and "Hardware expansion" have a very small, manufacturer-depenent overlap, so prepare for disappointment.

Comment: I've seen this, but my problem is it lists bridges and controllers, so im not too sure what to look out for in the output